# Changing Administrator

Tags: sudo, user-profile

Due to a mishap with my main profile I am wondering if anyone could assist me in making my secondary profile the administrator.

Something went wrong with my primary profile and I can no longer see anything but my desktop/shortcuts. I cannot get the command terminal to pop up or anything. Considering this last piece of information, I am interested in giving my secondary profile the administrator position so that I can use sudo commands. Otherwise, I cannot properly download programs.

Is there anyone who has knowledge on how to do this or has any other suggestions I can attempt? Thank you in advance!

Aaron

Comment: When you say user profile, I assume you mean a separate login?

Answer (score 3):

You can login to a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. There, login with your account (primary or secondary), and then give sudo privileges to your secondary profiles typing:

```
sudo adduser "username" sudo
```

replacing "username" by the name of your secondary account. This will add it to the sudoers group (named *sudo*, not admin).

Then, exit that terminal typing `exit`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to your X session, log out and login again. Now you should have sudo privileges.